# opening a window based on bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, window

I have created a bootstrap datepicker which is added in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLNfz/) which is derived from [bootstrap datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) library. Also I am trying to open a new window based on the clicked date as,

```
$("#calender").click(function(){
    var selDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
   var link = '/something&Date='+selDate;
    window.open(link, "_blank");
});
```

But when using the above code, if I click on month also the new window will open. How can i restrict the `window.open` method to open only if I clicked on the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the element clicked has the class day:

```
$("#calender").click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('day')) {
        var selDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var link = '/something&Date=' + selDate;
        window.open(link, "_blank");
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLNfz/1/)

Or restrict your selector (doesn't work, need to investigate...):

```
$("#calender .day").click(function (e) {
    var selDate =  $("#calender").datepicker('getDate');
    var link = '/something&Date=' + selDate;
    window.open(link, "_blank");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QaukQ/1/)

Comment: The first method works perfectly...! The second method wont work since it throws an invalid date.

Comment: Indeed, $(this) is not anymore the datepicker... But it didn't work if i replace it with $("#calender"), and double the datepicker if replaced by $(".datepicker"), that's strange...